# jQuery extend of jQuery UI autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete, jquery-widgets

I am trying to extend the default jQuery UI 1.8.16 autocomplete plugin to do a few things:

1. Check an array of values and not just the label/value when searching for a match
2. Render the menu item in a different pattern based on a category on the item

So to do this I began to work through the code. I am very new to writing a widget/plugin and so I am wondering if someone can help me understand this part. I am currently trying to do the following:

```
   $.widget("custom.advautocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
            filter: function (array, term) {

                var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i");
                return $.grep(array, function (value) {
                    return matcher.test(value.label || value.alldata || value);
                });
            },

            _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {

                var self = this,
                                currentCat = "";

                $.each(items, function (index, item) {

                    if (currentCat != item.category) {
                        ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
                        currentCat = item.category;
                    }

                    self._renderItem(ul, item);
                });
            },

            _renderItem: function (ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>")
                            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                            .append($("<a></a>").text(item.alldata))
                            .appendTo(ul);
            }
        });
```

The `_renderMenu` code is pretty much taken directly from the example in the documentation. The `_renderItem` code is working in this example as well.  What is not working is the filter code.  I did notice that the filter code is defined in the jQuery library like so:

```
$.extend($.ui.autocomplete, {
    escapeRegex: function (value) {
        return value.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
    },
    filter: function (array, term) {
        var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i");
        return $.grep(array, function (value) {
            return matcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
        });
    }
});
```

From what I've gathered so far, this is extending the `jQuery autocomplete` which is defined earlier by a call to `$.widget("ui.autocomplete"...`   But why is this handled this way?  Why are these two functions not handled inside the widget definition like everything else? I noticed that if I extend `ui.autocomplete` in the same manner as it is done by the base widget, then I can get the filter override to work.  I would like to extend the control and include the new filter at the same time so I can keep my code a bit cleaner but I don't understand why it is being done like this. Is there a benefit that I'm missing?

Comment: The reason `escapeRegex` and `filter` are defined *outside* of the normal widget is because they're *static* functions, meaning they are called like so: `$.ui.autocomplete.filter`. The other functions on the widget are called on an instance of the widget: `$("..").autocomplete("search", "");`

Comment: Thanks @AndrewWhitaker that is the exact answer I needed.  I am too new to extending jQuery to gather that on my own, but now I understand.

Comment: But, how we can keep/link newly extended filter function to work only with our custom widget(here, advautocomplete), so that it will not affect other normal autocomplete fields?